# Is it bad practice to request index.php in order to use other scripts

Tags: php, performance, code-structure

Is it bad to use `index.php` as loader for other scripts or does it make a difference?

i.e. requesting `index.php` with different query strings and inside it, selecting and including the matching script.

e.g.

`www.example.com/?sign-in` insteade of `www.example.com/sign-in.php`
`www.example.com/?new-post` insteade of `www.example.com/new-post.php`

In this way you can use `index.php` to do the common inclusions and processes, like, setting timezone, mb encoding, DB connection, auth, etc..

Comment: This question is better suited for programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: I don't think this is a bad practice. That's actually what the MVC-approach is based on. And I think it's quite a good idea to let requests be handled by a dispatcher instead of serving an actual file.

Answer (score 2):

Best practice is to let apache rewrite all urls to an `index.php` or some other file which you can use as bootstrap. This bootstrap runs all the basic code and then this bootstrap can figure out which other actions to take based on the url.

Every framework works like this.

several things you might want to do in the bootstrap:

- setup, autoloading classes
- setup mysql connection
- check if user is authenticated for a certain action

There are many tutorials on rewriting urls with apache: http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite

If you really want to learn about best practices i would suggest looking at existing frameworks, at how they implement certain things. eg: Zend or Symfony

Comment: Do some rsearch on "php routing" and mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 2):

Yes and No

The problem is that by doing it you will lose any SEO value, eg: domain.com/index.php?post=story will rank very poorly against domain.com/post/story . Also your index.php is going to get messy very quickly.

That being said MVC's usually use a index.php, so my url would be domain.com/users/edit/123 which is a very logical url, but what actually gets called is domain.com/index.php , it then looks at the first paramater, "users" and instantiates the user controller and then looks for the function edit inside that and passes the "123" (user id) as the first parameter in the function. If you are not familiar with MVC's I would advise codeigniter as a starting one, [more on codeigniter](http://codeigniter.com/).

In the end you will just be re-inventing the wheel by building it from scratch, rather use a MVC make development much easier.

Comment: while MVC is an estabilished pattern for web development, it's often overkill to use a big framework for small projects. I advocate the use of http://slimframework.com for starters and to learn the routing of urls through index.php, which is what OP is looking for.

Comment: In my opinion CI is very light, but each to his own.

Comment: I didn't say "heavy" but i said "big" because it's complete but forces you into MVC. Slim is a good starting point because it's more flexible.

Comment: The whole point of my answer is to get away of manual routing and get a MVC to do everything for you. While you might be right you lose some flexibility you can easily build an application of any size very quickly. Also CI scales much better for future.

Comment: But if you need just url routing for a small, enterprise internal website, a MVC is overkill as I said. Also, if you already have a collection of standalone scripts that you want to merge in a single portal through url routing, MVC can't be applied therefore, instead of doing manual routing, a small, clever framework like Slim is your best pick.

Comment: We do not know the scope of his project, nor whether he has existing code. He posted a question and gave my answer, I can understand your point, but I am not asking the question. If you are so adament write him your own answer...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28818/discussion-between-we0-and-stt-lcu)

Answer (score 1):

This is the best approach. You can take control of your website.
Create `index.php` and include other files on demand.
(Define a constant and use it in included files and so on) 
 But keep in mind to minimize `index.php` as much as possible.
Also you can use Apache `mod_rewrite` to generate SEO friendly URL.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of routing all your requests (through htaccess) to index.php you can also split the routes to map to other files:

`/blog/hello-there` mapping to `blog.php?title=hello-there`

`/sign/in` mapping to `login.php?login`

etc, thus you create your own simple routing based on the request URL; easy to read and easy to maintain.

This solution is suitable in small projects, for bigger project I advise to use a complete framework like Yii or Symfony.